# Custom motd in /etc/update-motd.d/20-fortune-cowsay only working partially

Tags: 16.04, lts, motd, fortune, cowsay

I have tried to create a custom motd on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've found that there is a `/etc/update-motd.d` directory with a few files. I've seen the pattern of `[00-99]-[name]`So I've added my own file called `20-fortune-cowsay`. It looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST"
fortune | cowsay
```

but the motd only looks like this

```
...
TEST
...
```

And I don't see the output of `fortune | cowsay`. Also, `echo "$(fortune | cowsay)"`, didn't help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="/usr/games:$PATH"
fortune | cowsay
```

"fortune" and "cowsay" are considered games by ubuntu and those are not in the default system path.